# Firebase Firestore where() query can't find document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time using `where().get()` for a Firestore query, and I can't get it to work. My Firestore data:

[image]

This code works:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Tunes').doc('tiny_dancer')
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
  if (querySnapshot.exists) {
    console.log(querySnapshot.data());
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
   console.error(error);
});
```

We get back `{composer: "elton_john"}`.

This code doesn't work:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Tunes')
.where('composer', '==', 'elton_john')
.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
  if (querySnapshot.exists) {
    console.log(querySnapshot.data());
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
   console.error(error);
});
```

The response is `No such document!` I was expecting it to return `tiny_dancer`. How do I do that?

Comment: I don't think there is an `exists` property on a `QuerySnapshot`. Did you mean to check [`empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `DocumentSnapshot.exists` property, to allow you to check if the document actually exist. But for a query there can be any number of matching documents, so instead of `exists` you'd use [`QuerySnapshot.empty`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty) to check if there are any matches.